# Converting strings to integers then ordering them in an list with strings

Tags: python

I have the following list and I need to order them from biggest to smallest names and numbers.

```
['joe:  5', 'ed:  9', 'joe:  7', 'ed:  8']
```

I'm having the following problems:

1. Converting the numbers from strings to integers to order it.
2. Ordering them with the correct string.

So my end result should be this:

```
['ed:  9', 'ed:  8', 'joe:  7', 'joe:  5']
```

Comment: Come on, what have you tried?

Comment: Aren't dictionaries more useful for this situation?
`my_var = {'joe': [5, 7], 'ed': [8, 9]}`. However, you can't have two keys with the exact same name, so I put them as lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> lis=['joe:  5', 'ed:  9', 'joe:  7', 'ed:  8']

>>> sorted(lis,key=lambda x:int(x.split()[-1]),reverse=True)
>>> ['ed:  9', 'ed:  8', 'joe:  7', 'joe:  5']
```

you can fetch the integers in each list item using `str.split`(as shown below), and that integer is then used to sort the list:

```
>>> int(lis[0].split(":")[1])
>>> 5

#or  

>>> int(lis[0].split()[1]) 
>>> 5
```

Comment: Does not work it keeps saying syntax error with the :, thanks though.

Comment: In [43]: lis=['joe:  5', 'ed:  9', 'joe:  7', 'ed:  8'] says syntax error after :

Comment: @user1903357 `In [43]:` is not part of the code, it's from the `IPython shell`. See I've updated the solution.